# Pesquisa no Google com resultados classificados do StackOverflow

Tags: debate

Fui fazer uma pesquisa no Google sobre um código qualquer e me retornou o seguinte:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que o Google classifica com destaque e ordena as respostas por número de votos da esquerda para a direita. Quando uma pergunta tem resposta aceita, ela aparece em primeiro lugar à esquerda.

Aparece inclusive uma seta para rolar os resultados ordenados por votos:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No print acima aparecem apenas resultados do SOen, mas também funciona com o SOpt.

Achei isso muito bom, sem falar na extrema utilidade, mas fiquei curioso. O que seria isto, uma parceria entre o Google e o SO ou o quê?

> Não fiquei certo de que seria um assunto pro META. Se não for, me
>   perdoem.

Comment: Legal! Eu achei essa notícia aqui: [Google now previews Stack Overflow answers directly in Search](https://thenextweb.com/google/2018/03/12/google-stack-overflow-preview/). Mas pra mim ainda aparece do jeito antigo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Conforme respondido [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304075/208518):

> Isto é uma experiência decorrente que a Google está a conduzir. Eles contactaram-nos há algum tempo e informaram-nos que estavam interessados em conduzir uma experiência que mostrasse mais informação adicional do nosso site, incluíndo fragmentos de repostas. Na altura iam focar-se na app e experiência web em dispositivos móveis, mas a experiência desktop também foi incluida nesta volta de testes. Ainda que a Google não precise da nossa permissão para isto, têm sido bastante comunicativos e estão a manter-nos a par de que experiências é que estão a conduzir, e vão partilhar dados sobre os resultados das experiências. Nós continuaremos a advogar fortemente pelo que pensamos ser o melhor para os nossos utilizadores, o que inclui tentar conduzi-los para longe de experiências ou resultados que achamos serem detrimentais para o envolvimento do novo utilizador e da comunidade no ecossistema.

Comment: Lindo Lindo Lindo!